# Using the import wizard how does one import lookup fields

Tags: data-import-wizard

I'm trying to import a csv into a non-standard object. I have no trouble mapping custom fields - name, phone, dates, etc. I'm having trouble importing a lookup field.

The lookup field isn't listed in the available fields there. Is there a reason for that? Or do i need to convert it to a master-detail field first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should by no fundamental difference between custom Master/Detail and Lookup fields - except that Master/Detail is always required.

In the Screenshot below you find a custom Object TestChild__c to be imported with a custom lookup field TestParent__c. As you see, you can match Lookups either with their Salesforce Id or with their Name.

[image]

Comment: Based on the answer,if we have Lookup Account in Contact field, we can use Name beside Id  to populate data?If the Name not much it will not update or add the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by Using External ID. First, create a Text Field in the object where you want to import the Lookup Field to. But remember to check the check boxes of Unique and External ID.

Goto dataloader.io, login, upload your CSV, while mapping, check the "lookup via" option and select the respective name. Done.